# How can I make a vanilla ganache which does not taste of white chocolate?

Tags: vanilla, ganache

I've been baking for quite a while, but now have started venturing myself onto the chocolate world. I'm very very intrigued by Laduree's vanilla ganache on their vanilla macaron as it doesn't taste like white chocolate! In fact, it tastes like a super concentrated vanilla ganache, which is so light and delicious at the same time!

I already tried all sorts of vanilla ganache (from Pierre Herme to Doris G - by the way, Herme's vanilla ganache took more than 30 hours to set up because of the cream-chocolate proportion).

Does anyone have any clues on how to achieve a vanilla ganache without the taste of white chocolate being too intrusive? I asked the lady at Laduree and she said it's a ganache and not a buttercream or creme de beurre.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Isn't vanilla ganache supposed to taste quite a bit like white chocolate?

Comment: I would have thought the ideal taste for vanilla ganache would be vanilla, jay. :P Rafaella, is there any particular reason you don't want to use a buttercream other than the fact that Laduree don't?

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! I know ganache is supposed to be made with chocolate, however vanilla is one of my passions and it's so hard to find products that taste 100% like vanilla! I would love to find a chocolate with no taste that could be added to my vanilla ganache just for texture purposes! The scent of vanilla is amazing... you should try Laduree's in case you haven't because that's truly amazing! Also, buttercream is not my first choice because it tends to be too buttery and not creamy at all. Any ideas ?! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use a soy and vegetable-fat based white chocolate like [Oppenheimer Kosher white chocolate chips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004V0NWA0). They are quite sweet, but lag behind on the chocolate-y taste. They temper well and behave in most ways I've used them like regular chocolate chips, except that for white chocolate taste they are a bit bland. These would make a good vehicle for a lighter but still sugary vehicle for vanilla.

Comment: Do you know any other brands that may have that chocolate ? I don't live in the US (I've been living in South America lately) and the only chocolates (good ones) they have available here is Callebaut (that I don't consider top notch) and Valrhona...

Comment: @Rafaella I order them through Amazon, I would imagine that if you search online for vegan white chocolate chips, or kosher ones you will be likely to find some with vegetable fats that limit the strength of the white chocolate flavor. You may also consider just cutting the chocolate with an alternative vegetable fat

Answer (score 4):

I think what you really are asking is what fats can be substituted for some of the cocoabutter that would give a lighter flavour or a flavour more suited to vanilla.

Perhaps a blend of:

coconut (high quality raw)
palm (highly processed and bland)
hydrogenated oils such as sunflower, rapeseed, soy (produced for confectionery manufacture)

Liquid oils such as my favorite for confectionery, macadamia, can be added in smaller amounts.

Answer (score 2):

For a white chocolate ganache but with a vanilla taste, I would suggest tempering with chocolate itself. You must lower the chocolate taste but raise the vanilla taste,. I suggest melting white chocolate and mixing it with some shortening, then I suggest folding it in with marshmallow fluff and using vanilla emulsion. I would rather use emulsion than than extracts any time. Or if not, simply add more powdered sugar but keep in the vanilla emulsion, even using a vanilla bean and scraping it out.